# sorting items in admin module - Symfony

Tags: sorting, symfony1

I have created an admin module and I'd like the items in the list view, to be able to 'sortable'
I've been looking at the following tutorial http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/sortable which seems to shed some light.

The problem is, I'd like the 'move up', 'move down' features in a a partial.

So, I don't want to create a listSuccess.php page, but I then don't have access to the $items object in the executeList() action.

Any ideas how I'd achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't need `$items`, you need only `$item->getId()`

Create a partial for a field, and inside that partial you will have access to current object being displayed.

You will also need to create `_list_footer/_list_header` to put Javascript code in.

Comment: But then how do I have access to: ItemPeer::getAllByRank() and ItemPeer::getMaxRank();